# What is tmpfs and why is it using most of my hdd space?

Tags: server, partitioning, 17.04

I installed Ubuntu Server to run a local Ark server, and am running out of disk space. When I went to check why (Since the ark install is only ~6GB and I allocated 30GB to the VM) I found that there are 5 filesystems called `tmpfs` that together use 16GB of HDD space, and another called `udev` that's using an additional 5GB.

Result of `df -h`:

[image]

Why are these eating up the majority of my space, and how do I move that space over to my filesystem so I can utilize it?

**Edit**: `/dev/sda1` is already 30GB, but I can only use 15GB of it?

Comment: Please add the output of `sudo lvdisplay` to your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

tmpfs and udev are virtual file systems. They don't allocate any disk space but dynamically use RAM to store their files. As their content is lost when you shutdown the system they are used for files which should not survive a reboot.

Comment: Hey Florian, can I reduce their size so I can expand the filesystem on home/douglas? Is there a minimum size they should be? I'm getting `Failed to preallocate: Not enough disk space` when trying to add files to my filesystem.

Comment: They don't exist on your disk so changing them doesn't help you here (as they only allocate as much memory as needed you can only specify a maximum but not a minimum size).

Answer (score 3):

Stumbled across this whilst looking for something else and noticed it was not adequately answered. So here is an explanation for anyone else who finds this.
Default ubuntu server creates a volume group but only assigns half of it to the root volume.

By coincidence your tmpfs use is about the same size as the unassigned space. I can see how you would assume that is where your HDD is being used up if you don't know how the filesystems work.

As explained by Florian, tmpfs are RAMdrives and have nothing to do with your HDD. 
udev is the device path, it also is not related to HDD space.

("Everything is a file" in linux)

What you need to do is run `lvdisplay`, it will show you your free space,

(assuming the entire HDD space was added to the pool by default)

To extend it use

```
lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/ubuntu-vg/root
```

(it should be that /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root maps to /dev/ubuntu-vg/root)

Once the volume is expanded you need to expand the filesystem, this can be done with

```
resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root
```

However, you're initial problem `Failed to preallocate: Not enough disk space` looks to have happened even though your `df -h` says 64% use.

Maybe the 5.0GB Available is the system reserved space, normally `df -h` doesn't show this. It could be you are trying to write into a read only space, I'm wondering if the /home/douglas/.Private mount has something to do with that.

You can check mount options with the `mount` command