# No space left on device (/dev/sda1)

Tags: mount, filesystem

I looged into a server and install a bunch of vagrant VMs (about 10 VMs). My system is a Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (kernel 4.4.0-138-generic), 40 CPUs, and 256 GB of memmory.

Suddenly, the server is telling that there's no space left on the device. I ran `df -h`

```
Filesystem                                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                                        126G     0  126G   0% /dev
tmpfs                                        26G  9.2M   26G   1% /run
/dev/sda1                                    16G   15G  399M  98% /
tmpfs                                       126G     0  126G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                       5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                                       126G     0  126G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                                        26G     0   26G   0% /run/user/111
```

and `df -i`

```
Filesystem                                   Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev                                       33002307    465 33001842    1% /dev
tmpfs                                      33007309    697 33006612    1% /run
/dev/sda1                                   1048576 124609   923967   12% /
tmpfs                                      33007309      1 33007308    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                      33007309      6 33007303    1% /run/lock
tmpfs                                      33007309     16 33007293    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                                      33007309      4 33007305    1% /run/user/111
```

Although `/dev/sda1` is full, there is plenty of space in the `tmpfs`. How do I use those filesystems instead of using just `/dev/sda1`?

Sorry if this questions is duplicate, but I'm looking at several different posts for hours and couldn't find a clear solution.
I can move my VMs to one of those tmpfs (will these be cleared in case the machine reboots?)

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is tmpfs and why is it using most of my hdd space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/914952/what-is-tmpfs-and-why-is-it-using-most-of-my-hdd-space)

Comment: How do I check that? This node is on a cluster. All I did was install vagrant and virtualbox

Comment: If 10 Vagrant VMs are taking up all your 16GB of disk space, then perhaps you can just have 9? Or perhaps the admin can give you more storage? Shifting VMs into RAM (tmpfs) may be a solution, but it has a bit of a learning curve...and requires approval of the admin.

Comment: You need to increase the size of your / device. 16G is too small.