# The tmpfs directory is not automatically cleared. Can I clear it manually?

Tags: filesystem

After restarting the computer, the tmpfs directory is not cleared.

```
df -h
Filesystem   Size  Used  Available Used% Mount on

tmpfs        1,6G  76K   1,6G      1%    /run/user/1000
```

How can I clear it manually?

Comment: I guess it contains __new__ files created by various software _after reboot._

Comment: I had problems when working with flash cards (input / output error) and after that this directory is not cleared. Perhaps this is unclean data that I deleted from the flash card (the size is the same)

Answer (score 0):

"/run/user/1000" (or another number, this is the uid of the user concerned) contains temp files used by running processes for that user, such as your keyring daemon, the audio system, the desktop environment ...

That directory is located on a `tmpfs` [virtual file system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/914952/what-is-tmpfs-and-why-is-it-using-most-of-my-hdd-space). A `tmpfs` file system is stored in RAM memory. It is dynamically resized, so it only takes the space actually needed for the files. It is created upon login, and removed when login out. **So yes, it is automatically cleared**. That you see files right after login in is because processes needed to run your desktop created them.

Clearly, this file system is managed by the system. Interfering with it as user will disrupt running processes.

Comment: kiril       1398  0.0  0.0 378344  6368 ?        Sl   10:06   0:00 /usr/libexec/gvfsd-fuse /run/user/1000/gvfs -f -o big_writes  - I kill this process. No more processes